# Wordpress contact form 7 to database

Tags: php, database, contact-form-7

I'm trying to build something in order to write the data from the WPCF7 form to some kind of database..
Is this possible?

I assume I will have to use some PHP for this? Where do I need to code this? Which file/page/...

Hosting is by Godaddy.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: dude, atleast make one google search attempt about your problem

Comment: there's a plugin called `contact form db` it takes care of that

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find the Plugin on WP, but have installed it by ZIP file, works like a charm! :)

Comment: you can also save your submission as a custom post using the plugin [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/)